# Selecting a collection via Python

Tags: python, interface, collections, outliner, select

Many similar question but none solved my problem.
My selection and hierarchy looks like this:
[image]

I want to loop through all selected collections, select the collection and it's children and export.
How to select it's children and export I already know but I have troubling selecting the collection.

```
import bpy

# Set the area to the outliner
area = bpy.context.area
old_type = area.type 
area.type = 'OUTLINER'

for x in bpy.context.selected_ids:
    if x.bl_rna.identifier == 'Collection':
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action = 'DESELECT')
        bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection = bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection.children[x.name]

# Reset the area 
area.type = old_type
```

But my code always throws the error:

```
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "Collection 5" not found'
```

Comment: It seems you're indistinctly talking about [LayerCollection](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.LayerCollection.html) and [Collection](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Collection.html) which are not the same thing. Could you elaborate on what you're trying to do ?

Comment: I updated my question a bit.
What is the difference between LayerCollections and Collections?

Comment: Thanks. What exactly do you want to export ? A Layer collection is an object that holds parameters that are specific to each view layer, wherehas a collection is an object that doesn't depend on the current view layer. They are linked in some way, but they are not the same thing. Working with layer collections is much, much more complicated than working with collections.

Comment: Than I guess I want to work with collections, since I want to select all objects that are inside a collection, mostly meshes and empties and export them, then repeat with the next collection

Comment: Including objects that are in children collections or only the ones that are directly in the collection ?

Comment: Including objects that are in children collections
Basically what you get when right click on a collection and hit "Select Objects".

Answer (score 3):

In your script, as shown above, the `type` of the `current area` is switched to Outliner. That´s the area you´ve run the script (Texteditor). Now you have two areas with type outliner and as Cod3R wrote in his answer, there´s no selection in the new one. Not so important, because only operators can get a list of selected data-blocks via bpy.context.selected_ids - see [here](https://developer.blender.org/rBaf008f553293)

Regarding your last comment, the panel is grayed out because that´s exactly what a poll function does. Wrong context sets operator inactive. In summary we need an context override for the operator which wants to get data from Outliner. In following example there´s a helper function for this. The queried data are stored in properties and an example with panel-operator is included to refresh data.

```
import bpy

# needs Blender 2.92 +

# outliner OP
class Outliner_OT_Items_Selected(bpy.types.Operator):    # only operators get selected Outliner items 
    bl_idname = 'outliner.items_selected'    
    bl_label = "Selected items in Outliner" 
    def execute(self,context):
        scene = context.scene
        scene['outl_items'] = context.selected_ids                                                  # all
        scene['outl_objs']  = [o for o in context.selected_ids if o.name in bpy.data.objects]       # only objs
        scene['outl_coll']  = [c for c in context.selected_ids if c.name in bpy.data.collections]   # only collections

        return {'FINISHED'}

# register outliner OP
bpy.utils.register_class(Outliner_OT_Items_Selected)

# storage
scene = bpy.data.scenes[bpy.context.scene.name]
scene['outl_items'] = []
scene['outl_objs'] = []
scene['outl_coll'] = []

# helper function
def call_op_with_override():
    ctxt = bpy.context.copy()                      # copy actual context
    for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:          # looping all areas in this workspace
        if area.type == 'OUTLINER':                # searching for area.type = Outliner to get right area      
            ctxt["area"] = area                    # change 'area' in ctxt (not area.type, this would change this area to type.Outliner)
            bpy.ops.outliner.items_selected(ctxt)  # now let OP do something in another context (override)
            break

# testcall script
call_op_with_override()   # if run script, we are in the Area with TextEditor, but we need Area with Outliner
print("\nselected Items:", [i.name for i in scene['outl_items']])
print("selected Objects:", [o.name for o in scene['outl_objs']])
print("selected Collections:", [c.name for c in scene['outl_coll']]) 

# Panel
class TESTPANEL_PT_Main(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = 'TEST_PANEL_PT_main'
    bl_label = "Test Panel"                      
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "TEST"
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        layout.label(text = "All Selected Items:")
        box = layout.box()          
        if scene['outl_items']:
            for i in scene['outl_items']:
                box.label(text = "- %s" % i.name if i is not None else "-deleted-")
        else:
            box.label(text = "no item selected", icon='ERROR')
            
        layout.label(text = "Selected Objects:")
        box = layout.box()          
        if scene['outl_objs']:
            for o in scene['outl_objs']:
                box.label(text = "- %s" % o.name if o is not None else "-deleted-")            
        else:
            box.label(text = "no object selected", icon='ERROR')
                        
        layout.label(text = "Selected Collections:")
        box = layout.box()          
        if scene['outl_coll']:
            for c in scene['outl_coll']:
                box.label(text = "- %s" % c.name if c is not None else "-deleted-")                            
        else:
            box.label(text = "no collection selected", icon='ERROR')
                    
        layout.operator('outliner.items_refresh', text="refresh")

        layout.separator()
        layout.label(text = "Active Items:")
        box = layout.box()  
        box.label(text = "Active Object: %s" % context.active_object.name if context.active_object is not None else "no active obj")
        box.label(text = "Active Collection: %s" % context.view_layer.active_layer_collection.name)

# OP refresh for panel
class Outliner_OT_Items_Refresh(bpy.types.Operator): 
    bl_idname = 'outliner.items_refresh' 
    bl_label = "refresh selection"  
    def execute(self,context):
        call_op_with_override()  # if run OP, we are in the Area with 3DView, but we need Area with Outliner

        # ... do what you want here
        [o.hide_set(False) for o in scene['outl_objs']] # unhide selected objs
            
        return {'FINISHED'}                           
       
# register Panel + OP refresh
bpy.utils.register_class(TESTPANEL_PT_Main)
bpy.utils.register_class(Outliner_OT_Items_Refresh)
```

Comment: A bit more complicated than I hoped for, but I should be able to work through this.
But when I run the script in the text editor, the panel does not recognize that I have a collection selected, even when I hit refresh

Comment: Hmm...strange. Just tested with 2.93.7 and 3.0.0 and it works. Did you use 2.92 or higher? Are multiple outliners open? And we are talking about selected items, not active ones? Script edited.

Comment: It is really awkward to have to use an operator to access selected items... I really hope they'll expand this feature to be more usable in the future.

Comment: I am using 3.0.0, only one outliner is open, displaying the active collection works, but displaying the selected ones does not

Comment: Script changed again to catch errors when items are deleted. @ Lala_Ghost I can´t find a way to make it not work. Are there multiple scenes in your file?

Comment: I completely close all Blender instances, open a new Blender 3.0.0 instance, go to the scripting tab, paste your code into the text editor and run it, create a new collection, select it and hit "refresh" in your new panel, but still nothing

But it works in version 2.9.3...

Answer (score 1):

Did you notice that your selection is different when you switch text editor to outliner? I think you have to code an operator and run it in the current outliner (f3) or add a button.

```
import bpy

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "outliner.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Outliner Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.area.type == 'OUTLINER'

    def execute(self, context):
        sel = []
        for i in context.selected_ids:
            if i.bl_rna.identifier == 'Collection':
                sel.append(i)
        
        for i in sel:
            bpy.ops.object.select_all(action = 'DESELECT')
            for o in i.objects:
                o.select_set(True)
                 
            # Export ...
        
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: I don't understand why do I need to use the poll function with context.area.type == 'OUTLINER' here.
Couldn't I just do it without it?
My class if of type Operator & ExportHelper and gets loaded into a button inside a panel in the end.

Comment: When I leave the poll method in and load it as an operator into a panel it is greyed out and not clickable

Is there maybe a workaround?